# Review audit answer seems identical to non-deleted answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11049437) by saying the answer looks okay.

It answers the question and describes the linked content sufficiently.

What confuses me most is that two other answers to that question are identical. They provide a link and describe it briefly.

Am I missing something? The link is also not shortened.